# Django CMS not publishing draft to live state

Tags: django-cms

I have a django-cms project with a live page that works.  But I have been heavily editing it.  It looks like I want it in the draft but when I publish it it shows the original page not the new draft.  If I go back to draft all my changes are there.  They just wont save to live.

Answer (score 4):

I can think of three possible problems:

1. Your tree is broken. You can fix this with the command `python manage.py fix-mptt`, or `python manage.py fix-tree` for newer versions of the Django CMS.
2. There are other problems with the cms. You can find them with the command `python manage.py cms check`.
3. Caching. For some reason, it might happen, that you still see the cached version of the CMSPlugin after publishing your changes. In this case, waiting will help.